# Print list when I have two P after each other

Tags: python, list, random

Hello I'm trying to make a code (to stop when I have two P) but it makes me : 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Thanks for your help ! 
My code :

```
import random as rd
def experience ():
    L=[]
    L.append(rd.choice(['P','F']))
    L.append(rd.choice(['P','F']))
    a=0
    b=1
    while L[a]!=L[b]!='P':
        a=b
        b=b+1
        L.append(rd.choice(['P','F']))
    return L
```

Comment: On what line is the error thrown?  Can you post the full error?  And is `L[a] != L[b] != 'P'` valid?

Comment: Works for  me...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *I'm trying to make a code (to stop when I have two P)*?  Like two `P`s in a row?  You're only populating the list with two values.  Why the second `while` statement?  All you'd need to do in this scenario is check the first and second indices of `L`, because there's only two values in it.

Comment: What is the python version ? in 2.7 working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the exception you mention, but are you sure your exit condition is correct?

Wouldn't "while not (L[a]==L[b]=='P'):" be more correct if you want to quit when you have two 'P' after each other?

Or perhaps even "while not (L[a]=='P' and L[b]=='P'):" to make it more readable since two "==" in the same statement can easily be misunderstood.

Here's a shorter implementation by the way, there's really no need to keep track of indices:

```
def experience():
    L = [rd.choice(['P', 'F'])]
    while True:
        L.append(rd.choice(['P', 'F']))
        if L[-1] == L[-2] == 'P':
            return L
```